# What is the name of global variable in bigcommerce which is used to store customer group name

Tags: bigcommerce

What is the name of global variable in bigcommerce which is used to store customer group name? And how can I get the current customer's group name?

Answer (score 1):

It's `%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%%`

Note that there is also `%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%%`, if you need.